# JavaScript:conver array of string into textarea

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, textarea

I have array of string, how i can conver it into textArea?

Comment: Please clarify; put the text in the array into an existing textarea?

Comment: What do you mean by convert to text area?

Comment: You should first transform it into a set of buttons, retrieve labels and fill your textarea ... or not

Comment: yes, i have textarea element and i have a array of strings which came from handler, and i need put all value from this array into textarea.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('textareaId').innerHTML = ['Hello', 'World'].join(', ');
```

Comment: i have textarea element and i have a array of strings which came from handler, and i need put all value from this array into textarea.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the textarea loaded in the DOM, use Speransky Danil's answer.

If not, you can use

```
function arrayToTextarea(arr){
    var txt=document.createElement('textarea');
    txt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr.join(', ')));
    return txt;
}
```

And then you can use

```
document.body.appendChild(arrayToTextarea(myarray));
```